# Using natural deduction, show that: ∀x.(P (x) → Q(x)), ∃x.P (x) ⊢N ∃x.Q(x)

Tags: logic

1. How I would show: **∀x.(P (x) → Q(x)), ∃x.P (x) ⊢N ∃x.Q(x)** using Natural Deduction?
2. Would I not need to know what P(x) and Q(x) are to prove soundness and completeness?

Comment: For your first question, what did you try and where did you get stuck? It's hard to offer real help (rather than just solving the exercise for you) without knowing what part you had difficulty with.

Comment: I highly recommend renaming bound variables so that the problem is to show that $\forall x . (P(x) \to Q(x)), \exists y . P(y) \vdash \exists z . Q(z)$. In my experience this helps students.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am stuck from the begging. I believe that I need to start with the removal of ∃, however, this can only be completed on the RHS of ⊢? Same with ∀? Would a box proof be easier to see?

Comment: @AndrejBauer even if I change the bound variables (which I agree is easier to see), I am still in the same boat. 
I know that this is an intuitive proof, I can see it from reading it. The issue is, I do not have enough practice with quantifiers and am running into issues on starting the proof.

Comment: For us to really help, you would have to tell us which particular version of natural deduction you are using (which textbook)? Since this is a problem for you, it may well be the case that if I show you the solution  in notation that is slightly different from the one you're using, you'll be out of luck again. Should the proof be displayed with boxes? As a tree?

Comment: @AndrejBauer :: Mathematical Logic for Computer Science by Lu Zhongwan (http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3434)
A box proof is fine; even inference notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would like to prove $(\forall x . P(x) \to Q(x)), (\exists y . P(y)) \vdash \exists z . Q(z)$.

Let us first do it in plain language, but still in natural deduction. We have hypotheses

1. $(\forall x . P(x) \to Q(x))$
2. $\exists y . P(y)$

We use hypothesis 2: there is $a$ such that $P(a)$.
We use hypothesis 1 applied to the case $x := a$ to obtain:

3. $P(a) \to Q(a)$.

We already know that $P(a)$, therefore we can use 3 to get $Q(a)$. We therefore conclude that $\exists z . Q(z)$. QED.

I am not going to draw boxes because you can get them on the web:

- go to [ProofWeb](http://prover.cs.ru.nl/login.php) and in the section called "Proof assistants on the web" login as guest and select the Coq proof assistant.
- under the "Display menu option select "Fitch style box proofs" or "Gentzen-style tree proofs"
- type the following code into the left-hand window:

  ```
  Parameter A : Set.
  Parameter P : A -> Prop.
  Parameter Q : A -> Prop.

  Lemma foo: (forall x, P(x) -> Q(x)) -> (exists y, P(y)) -> exists z, Q(z).
  Proof.
    intros H1 H2.
    destruct H2 as [a H2'].
    exists a.
    apply (H1 a).
    exact H2'.
  Qed.​
  ```
- Now move down line by line with the "down" arrow in the upper-left corner. Watch the proof unfold in the lower-right text area.

Comment: Thank you! One last question, when completing these proofs (specifically this textbooks notation), it infers that we must eliminate $\forall$ from the RHS. Does this mean epsilon rule must be applied to show reflexivity prior? i.e. to remove the $\forall x$ must we apply the  $\epsilon$-rule to show that $\forall x. (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ is on the RHS as well?

Comment: What "right-hand side" and what "$\epsilon$-rule"?

Answer (score 4):

> Would I not need to know what $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are to prove soundness and completeness?

No. The phrase "formal logic" isn't the opposite of "casual logic": rather, it means, logic based on the form (i.e., structure) of propositions, not on their interpretation as statements about the world. In formal logic, the statements "Socrates is a man; all men are mortal; therefore, Socrates is mortal" has exactly the same form as "sploon is a fneep; every fneep is blunfish; therefore, sploon is blunfish", and "$\big(P(a) \land \forall x\,(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\big)\rightarrow Q(a)$". The logical truth is independent of any meaning you might want to ascribe to $P$ and $Q$.

Also, soundness and completeness are properties of proof systems, not individual formulae so your question seems to contain a category error.

Comment: "casual logic" - also known as "not actually logic"?

Comment: @G.Bach also known as "bro logic"

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you, this clarified quite a bit! How would you then know if something is sound and complete in proof systems? Are there guidelines the proof must meet?

Comment: @JollyGr33nGiant That's way too broad a question for Stack Exchange! And, again, soundness and completeness are properties of proof *systems*, not individual proofs. Are you sure you've understood those two terms correctly?